# Corda 4.1: How to make a query of PersistentState with a field in its embeded object?

Tags: corda

In my code `contractId` belongs to `PersistentDeal`, which is an embedded object of `PersistentDealState`. `PersistentDealState` is the schema for `DealState` which extends from `ContractState`.

How to get `DealState` giving `contractId` as a query parameter to the query cryteria?

This query criteria does not work

```
val result = builder {
        val criteria = DealSchemaV1.PersistentDealState::deal.equal(DealSchemaV1.PersistentDeal::tcmContractID.equal(contractId))
        val queryCriteria = QueryCriteria.VaultCustomQueryCriteria(expression = criteria, contractStateTypes = setOf(DealState::class.java),status = status)
        vaultService.queryBy<DealState>(queryCriteria)
    }
```

Here are my models

```
@Entity
    @Table(name = "DealState",
            indexes = [Index(name = "contract_id_index", columnList = "contract_id")])
    class PersistentDealState(

            @Embedded
            var deal: PersistentDeal

            some other fields...

    ) : PersistentState()


    @Embeddable
    class PersistentDeal(

            @Column(name = "contract_id")
            var contractID: Long,

            some other fields...
    )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not currently possible to use the `VaultCustomQueryCriteria` to specify filterable criteria for embedded objects.
Please raise an Issue (https://github.com/corda/corda/issues) via our GitHub website to request this.

The current options available are to use a JDBC session:
https://docs.corda.net/head/api-persistence.html#jdbc-session

or a JPA Entity Manager (and HQL):
https://docs.corda.net/head/api-persistence.html#jpa-support